# function that uses guards and a where clause then I want to change it using recursion

Tags: haskell, recursion, where-clause, guard

I am trying implement a function that can check scores and a list of all the scores in the class and then tells you by producing a string what do you get are you above the average or not. It should be as the following expression :

```
scoreChecker 45 [19,33,40,66,11,77]  ==  "You're better than average!!"
scoreChecker 30 [19,33,40,66,11,77]  ==  "Sorry, you're below the average :-("
scoreChecker 41 [19,33,40,66,11,77]  ==  "Precisely average"
scoreChecker 100 []                  ==  "Sorry, you're not using it correctly"
```

My attempt is this, but I am getting an error:

```
scoreChecker :: Double -> [Double] -> String
scoreChecker _ [] = "Sorry, you're not using it correctly"
scoreChecker avg (x:xs)
| x <= xs   = "You're better than average!!"
| x == xs    = "Precisely average"
| otherwise avg  = "Sorry, you're below the average :-(" 
     where 
           scores       = [19,33,40,66,11,77]
            avg         = scores / length
```

I hope some experts would help, I am learning the language my first time. 
Thanks all.

my output:

```
parse error on input `='
```

Comment: What is the `Double` argument to this function supposed to be?  You haven't specified it in `scoreChecker (x:xs)`

Comment: what sort of error are you getting? If it doesn't compile, please paste the exact output. If it gives incorrect results, please give an example.

Comment: Also, please post the error you're getting, without the error it's hard to know what went wrong.

Comment: Equations for `scoreChecker' have different numbers of arguments
      recursion.hs:2:1-58
      recursion.hs:(3,1)-(7,36)
Failed, modules loaded: none. Thats what it error I am getting

Comment: @wadbarca The error message tells you exactly what's wrong, you haven't specified the same number of arguments between `scoreChecker _ []` and `scoreChecker (x:xs)`.

Comment: Please install `ghc`. That is clearly not `ghc` output.

Comment: This is Prelude a module for Haskell! But thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

Note the following....

- The function should always have two inputs....  Yet the second case has one.
- `xs` is a list, avg is not.  How can you use (<=) between those.
- Your definition of avg is not mathematically correct.

Comment: I updated my attempt based on your notes. Could you give it a look Thanks

Comment: @wadbarca: `avg` isn't lined up with `score`. Also I think you need space before `|`s. You also will have a type error with `length`

Comment: The space is it only typo in this site i get it right. Thanks